# tomcat max number of threads

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, threads, concurrency

I have a very confusing scenario.. We are using tomcat6 to host an internal application. In server.xml file maxthreads attributes is set to 150 but if I log on to the manager, in "http-8080" section I see max threads = 40. So it saying that the remaining 110 threads are hidden to serve other protocols or is the maxthreads attribute is overwritten somewhere else?

one more thing is that our QA has done performance test(wiht LoadRunner) on the application with 700 concurrent users and they say that at a time there are only 90 connections to the server at max. Why is this 90? why isn't it 40 as that is the max threads acoording to the manager or 150- as I originally set it to be?

Comment: Does [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/212190/tomcat6-maxthreads-property-ignored) help?

Comment: @Alex.. thanks for your reply.. following Milen's comment in that link, I checked my server.xml and the Executor is configured to 150 threads... so back to square1.. why is it 40 on tomcat manager page instead of 150?